# Erro ao construir um filtro de buscas Java Script

Tags: javascript, filtro

Estou fazendo um desafio na Digital House. Segue a descrição:

> Uma loja virtual permite a seus visitantes filtrar produtos pelo preço. Existe um array com os preços dos produtos. Um programador já criou uma função maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) que retorna um array com os preços dos produtos mais baratos que o valor passado como parâmetro. Outro programador já criou uma função maisCarosQue(valor, precos) que retorna um array com os preços mais caros que o valor passado como parâmetro. Chegou sua vez!

> Crie uma função precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos) que deve utilizar as funções maisBaratosQue e maisCarosQue para retornar os preços que estão entre o valorMenor e o valorMaior. Sua função deve receber então dois parâmetros:

> valorMenor para representar o valor mínimo dos preços a serem listados

> valorMaior para representar o valor máximo dos preços a serem listados

> precos para representar um array com os preços dos produtos

> Ela deve retornar um array com todos os preços entre valorMenor e valorMaior.

O desafio já veio com 2 funções pré-construídas. São elas:

```
function maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p <= valor);
}


function maisCarosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
}
```

Qual seria uma possível solução para este desafio. Tentei diversas formas porém, não consegui.

Segue abaixo minha tentativa.

```
function maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p <= valor);
}

var array1 = maisBaratosQue()

function maisCarosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
}

var array2 = maisCarosQue()

function precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos){
   for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
      var valoresBaratos = array1[array1.indexOf(i)]
      if (valoresBaratos != valorMenor){
         return
      }
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
      var valoresCaros = array2[array2.indexOf(i)]
      if (valoresCaros != valorMaior){
         return
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8388/103217

Comment: Desculpe pessoal, agora que li as diretrizes. Obrigado @Danizavtz

Comment: Vou reformular a pergunta com minha tentativa de solução

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa entenderas funções existentes

```
function maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p <= valor);
}

var maisBaratos = maisBaratosQue(10,[1,3,4,100,1000]) //  São esses os mais baratos que 10 -> [1, 3, 4]
```

e

```
function maisCarosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
}

var maisCaros= maisCarosQue(4,[1,3,4,100,1000]) // são esses os mais maior igual a 4 -> [4 ,100, 1000]
```

Uma forma de fazer o calculo da função 'precosEntre' é calcular a intercessão entre maisCarosQue(valorMenor, precos) e maisBaratosQue(valorMaior, precos);

que pode ser feita tb com o filter.

```
let intersection = maisCaros.filter(x => maisBaratos.includes(x));
// nesse caso entre 4 e 10 tem só o valor 4 no array [1,3,4,100,1000]
```